# How can I clear the cache of postgresql in a docker container?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, dockerfile

I'm using kubernethese and postgresql docker container and I'm trying to analyse the performance of some queries such as:

```
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from table1  as t1, table2 as t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.status=true and t2.status=true
```

I found that the query refers to memory cache after each execution.How can I clear the cache of postgresql in a docker container?

Comment: do you know how to do it in an instance of postgresql outside docker? if yes then you can probably just exec that command in the running container `docker exec`

Comment: Or rather `kubectl exec` https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

Comment: Running with a completely cleared cache is not a realistic situation. (think: catalogs) Either you run the test-query with a *warm* cache, or you run a second query (or rerun the same query with different selection criteria)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to measure the performance but it is not a production database, you could just stop the pod and restart it. Make sure that the database has persistence using volumes and then simply execute `kubectl delete pod <name of the pod>`. If you are using Deployments or DaemonSets, the pod should start again with the cache clean.

Comment: For the persistance of database do you mean this **volumeMounts:
        - name: vm-backend-db
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data**